# reactstrap - create-react-app - not found bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css - v.4

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am new in this. I am trying to create a react app with bootsrap 4. I am using **reactstrap** following the next steps:

```
create-react-app my-app

npm install bootstrap --save

npm install --save reactstrap@next react react-dom
```

Import Bootstrap CSS in the src/index.js file:
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

But when I start my app, I am getting this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in 'D:\React\my-app2\src'

I used to use bootstrap with CDN, you know, in my html page,  ***link rel="stylesheet" ... etc and script src=""... etc***. But using **reactstrap**, where are the js files? (jquery, popper, bootstrap) (are all together when I run **npm install bootstrap --save** ?)

Thanks

Comment: Go take a look inside the `./node_modules/bootstrap` folder and you'll be able to see where is located your css file.

Answer (score 7):

As you see from the error, it tries to look for *bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css* inside your *src* folder. But if you look at your project files, you will notice that the *bootstrap* folder is located 1 level up (in the root) inside *node_modules* folder.

So either search and correct your path to:

`../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`.

Or add (if you still haven't done this) a reference to your **index.js**:

`import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`.

---

This is the files tree:

```
+-node_modules
 |-bootstrap
  |-dist
   |-css
    |-bootstrap.css
+-src
 |-index.js
```

Comment: just simply amazing , and I am wondering why all the tutorials have such a path **import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';** ?  any thoughts on that?

Comment: The file structure might depend on the tutorial. The best way is to know where the CSS file is located, what is the pass to it and use it.